# Should one include tests in a packaged gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been looking around documentation and example famous gems for the answer to a simple question:

#### Should one include tests in one's PACKAGED gem, and if so, why?

Put a different way, do you add test files to the `files` gemspec attribute, and do you include test dependencies via `add_development_dependencies`? And if so, *why*?

It makes perfect sense to me to test gems and include tests in the gem's source repository. It makes less sense to me to include tests along with the deployed source code packaged up in the gem. Is there a standard means for people to use a gem's tests from rubygems?

That said, it seems like many major projects include tests, so I have to be missing something, right?

Comment: If you have huge test files, maybe not, keep the `.gem` footprint lean. If they're small, why not?

Comment: Why yes? If there's no easy way for users to run gem tests that's guaranteed to work (i.e., rubygems doesn't include a known hook to invoke a gem's test), how are they useful?

Comment: If they're of trivial size, don't sweat it, another 6KB of code isn't going to kill anyone. If they're huge, don't bother including them. There's  a ton of junk in gems, tests are usually the last of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to include tests in your gem files. However, if the test files are tiny (which they probably are), then it's no big deal.

For a long time, when creating a new gem with the command `bundle gem mygemname`, the following lines were included in the generated `gemspec`:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  s.test_files = s.files.grep(/^(test|spec|features)\//)
  # ...
end
```

Since your tests were being included already, in the `test_files`, it literally didn't matter that they were included in the `files`, too.

However, if you run the same command `bundle gem mygemname` today, then instead you'll see this line in the generated `gemspec` file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.files  = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  # No mention of s.test_files !
  # ...
end
```

What changed?

Well, `s.test_files` is now *almost* deprecated. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/735) in RubyGems to not install test_files, which has been deferred to a post-2.x RubyGems release due to 'backward compatibility'. It also used to be possible to run tests for a Gem whilst installing it, with `gem install -t gemname`; this feature has now been [removed](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/429f883210f8b2b38ea310f7fc6636cd0e456d5c) (see bug #25707).

This is, I believe, why you still see lots of gems with test files included in the source code. But there's no longer any point including them.